How to compose variables sampled from Probability Density Functions , and apply multivariable Leibniz Integral Rule?
If $x_1$ is sampled from $p_1$ (probability density function) with domain $\Omega_1$, and $x_2$ is sampled from $p_2$ with domain $\Omega_2$, etc up to $x_n$,
For an arbitrary function $f$, I can work out that the PDF of $f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ is
$$t \mapsto \frac{\rm d}{\rm dt} \int_{} p_1(x_1)\cdot p_2(x_2) \cdots p_n(x_n)\\
\begin{array} {rcl} x_1 & \in & \Omega_1 \\ x_2 & \in & \Omega_2 \\ & \vdots & \\ x_n & \in & \Omega_n \\ f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) & < & t \end{array}
$$
I'm wondering if there is a nice way to transform that formula using something like Leibniz Integral Rule (LIR).  Especially in the $n=2$ case.  I expect that in the $n=2$ case, it converts the area integral into a (possibly piecewise) line integral.
I can brute force apply the 1 dimensional LIR in a case by case basis but the result is a formula that is not symmetric in the various $x$ like the above formula is.  I'm looking for something cleaner than just applying LIR $n$ times.
Since the integrand does not depend on $t$ the integral term of LIR disappears to $0$.  But the inequality in the domain adds an extra complication.
I'm fine with an answer that uses determinants, Jacobians, etc, common multivariable differential calculus stuff.  But I'd like to avoid obscure notation from differential geometry unless it can be explained, possibly with something like a nontrivial example, such as an example that doesn't assume $p_k(x_k) = 1$.
